# weird error with django-celery or python

Tags: python, django, macos, celery

I'm having trouble running tasks. I run `./manage celeryd -B -l info`, it correctly loads all tasks to registry.

The error happens when any of the tasks run - the task starts, does its thing, and then I get:

```
[ERROR/MainProcess] Thread 'ResultHandler' crashed: ValueError('Octet out of range 0..2**64-1',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 221, in run
    return self.body()
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 458, in body
    on_state_change(task)
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 436, in on_state_change
    state_handlers[state](*args)
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 413, in on_ack
    cache[job]._ack(i, time_accepted, pid)
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/concurrency/processes/pool.py", line 1016, in _ack
    self._accept_callback(pid, time_accepted)
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/job.py", line 424, in on_accepted
    self.acknowledge()
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/job.py", line 516, in acknowledge
    self.on_ack()
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 405, in ack
    message.ack()
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/kombu/transport/base.py", line 98, in ack
    self.channel.basic_ack(self.delivery_tag)
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqplib-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/amqplib/client_0_8/channel.py", line 1740, in basic_ack
    args.write_longlong(delivery_tag)
  File "/Users/jzelez/Sites/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqplib-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/amqplib/client_0_8/serialization.py", line 325, in write_longlong
    raise ValueError('Octet out of range 0..2**64-1')
ValueError: Octet out of range 0..2**64-1
```

I also must note that this worked on my previous Lion install, and even if I create a blank virtualenv with some test code, when a task runs it gives this error.

This happens with Python 2.7.2 and 2.6.4.

```
Django==1.3.1
amqplib==1.0.2
celery==2.4.6
django-celery==2.4.2
```

Comment: What's delivery_tag? Use pdb.pm() to get into the stacktrace and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is some bug with homebrew install python. I've now switched to the native Lion one (2.7.1) and it works.

Comment: Plus you could brew upgrade to Python 2.7.3 to solve the issue.